# Webkit based browser with a Native video player

Tags: qt, browser, webkit, media-player

I am working on a Webkit based browser and created the general layout of a browser. But i want to have a native mediaplayer integrated with this browser, as webkit by default doesnot provide any. Please help me as to how i can integrate a media player with the webkit engine, so that atleast .mp4 files work. Can you please point from where i can begin as i don have any kind of knowledge in media players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use libvlc.
There is a good wrapper class available on codeproject which you can directly use
Here is the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38952/VLCWrapper-A-Little-C-wrapper-Around-libvlc
or you can directly have a look at
Qt vlc port
http://projects.tano.si/vlc-qt

Answer (score 1):

You can use an embedded javascript video player like one of these:

- [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com/)
- [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/)
- [SublimeVideo](http://www.sublimevideo.net/)

Embed one of those scripts into your application, and run the videos from within your QWebView